# docker cp cannot get exist file

Tags: docker

Following is my code:

```
~ $ docker exec minikube ls /tmp
gvisor
h.876
h.951
hostpath-provisioner
hostpath_pv
nginx.tar
~ $ docker cp minikube:/tmp/nginx.tar /tmp/nginx.tar
Error: No such container:path: minikube:/tmp/nginx.tar
```

/tmp/nginx.tar exist in container but cannot cp, how to fix

Comment: Can you try copying the entire directory instead?

Answer (score 0):

Exec `docker ps -a` get container Id and use it in your command.

Then run `docker cp {CONTAINER_ID}:/tmp/nginx.tar ~`

`~` is for your home directory, dont copy to temp directory its protected one.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fix docker cp err but I find another way to cp:

```
docker exec cat /tmp/nginx.tar > /tmp/nginx.tar
```